# how do I load a dict type directly to an rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, rdd

I have a dictory in python

```
{'609232972': 4, '975151075': 4, '14247572': 4, '2987788788': 4, '3064695250': 2}
```

how can I directly load this in rdd, without loosing the key value pair?

When I load it like this

```
usr_group = sc.parallelize(partition)
print(usr_group.take(5))
```

I just breaks up the key value pair and gives

```
['609232972', '975151075', '14247572', '2987788788', '3064695250']
```

I am expecting the RDD to break into

```
{'609232972': 4, '975151075': 4, '14247572': 4, '2987788788': 4, '3064695250': 2}
```

so that I can process the key-value pair together

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you want the rdd to have as a row, but here are three options:

```
my_dict = {'609232972': 4, '975151075': 4, '14247572': 4, '2987788788': 4, '3064695250': 2}
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([my_dict])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(list(my_dict.iteritems()))
rdd3 = rdd2.map(lambda x: (dict([x])))
print rdd1.collect()
print rdd2.take(4)
print rdd3.take(4)
```

> [{'2987788788': 4, '975151075': 4, '3064695250': 2, '14247572': 4,
>   '609232972': 4}]
>
> [('2987788788', 4), ('975151075', 4), ('3064695250', 2), ('14247572',
>   4)]
>
> [{'2987788788': 4}, {'975151075': 4}, {'3064695250': 2}, {'14247572':
>   4}]